# two differents method or additional parameter?

Tags: c#

I have a method set in an POCO entity that set the basic property and the navigation property. In some cases, I don't need to verify some conditions, but in another cases I need to verify to ensure that the information is coherent in the database, but this verification makes me to get extra data from database.

So by the moment I have my basic method that is this:

```
public void setMyProperty(MyType paramProperty)
{
    this.Property = paramProperty;
    this.IDProperty = paramProperty.IDPorperty;
    paramProperty.MyNavigationCollection.Add(this);
}
```

For the method that verifies the data, I guess that I have two options.

First one, I can create a new method for business logic, somthing like that:

```
public void setPropertyBi(MyType paramProperty)
{
   //check conditons
   //If all OK then
   this.setPorperty(paramProperty);
}
```

But I have another option, use only one method, not the basic method and the other for business checks. Something like that:

```
public void setProperty(MyType paramType, bool paramDoChecks)
{
    if(paramDoChecks)
    {
        //Do checks
    }


    //if all OK
    this.Property = paramProperty;
    this.IDProperty = paramProperty.IDPorperty;
    paramProperty.MyNavigationCollection.Add(this);
}
```

Which is the recommended option? or there are another ways?

Comment: IMHO The second option is better.

Comment: Primarily opinion-based, isn´t it?

Comment: Definitely opinion based; OP - read up on optional parameters if you haven't already - you'll know more about possible options.

Comment: @HimBromBeere hence IMHO :-)

Comment: Anything you can extract to a logic entity should become either a member or a class. So when you feal there´s a part of your code doing a specific task, extract a method that describes what this task it. There´s no general rule to this how you´re achieving this, this is why I voted to close that question.

Comment: It's nevertheless interesting that in this short amount of time so many people argue for the boolean flag. With respect to [Martin's Clean Code](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1392524) I usually tend to avoid such flags. They lead to less readable code and sometimes even introduce code smells.

Comment: @HimBromBeere first thanks for your comments and really I appreciate you explain why for voting to close the post. It is the way to learn too why I get downvoted for example, or the reason why you considerate to close the post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

People here seem to prefer the flag, I personally think it is horrible.
You want to achieve two different things: just set a property; validate AND set a property. IMHO it should be two separated methods.

Comment: Guilherme to the rescue. :)

Comment: totally agree...

Comment: Agree too.  An additional benefit of splitting into 2 is that you can use different visibility, for example protected on the property and publc on the setter method.

Answer (score 0):

Just don´t write two different Methods if it´s one equaly functionality. Just add a Parameter which makes the validation-difference like you´ve written last.
But don´t forget to enter the behaviour if validation failed. separate it well.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a Boolean `ValidationRequired`property to `MyType` which you can set before the call to `setMyProperty()`.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer to have two methods: *CanSetProperty* and *SetProperty*.

- *CanSetProperty*: just check the condition, does not change anything in the parameter.
- *SetProperty*: will modify the paramenter.

I think this code is a good candidate to follow the [Command Query Separation Pattern](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/CommandQuerySeparation.html)

> The fundamental idea is that we should divide an object's methods into
>   two sharply separated categories:
>
> - Queries: Return a result and do not change the observable state of the
>     system (are free of side effects).
> - Commands: Change the state of a
>     system but do not return a value.